# Al momento de generar un reporte en PDF con una plantilla me manda Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_list_encodings()

Tags: php, linux, pdf, xampp

Subí mi aplicación Web a un servidor Linux y a la hora de querer generar un reporte PDF me manda el error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_list_encodings()
in /var/www/html/Integradorav7/models/pdf/src/Cpdf.php:428
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/Integradorav7/models/pdf/src/Cezpdf.php(279): Cpdf->__construct(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/Integradorav7/persona_report.php(12):
Cezpdf->__construct('letter', 'landscape')
#2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/Integradorav7/models/pdf/src/Cpdf.php on line 428
```

Alguien que esté familiarizado con este error o que conozca de donde viene? ya que lo probé en el Localhost de XAMPP y sí me da el reporte, el problema es al subirlo al servidor.

**Nota:** Cabe mencionar que utilizo una plantilla para el PDF

Comment: Creo que solo falta habilitar la extensión `mbstring`; por lo general solo hay que editar el archivo `php.ini`. En [este artículo](https://www.wpsysadmin.com/requerimientos/saludsitio-modulo-php-mbstring/) mencionan algunas opciones para habilitarla de acuerdo al tipo de servidor y panel de control.

Comment: Si es linux, debes incluir mbstring en la instalación de PHP: `apt/yum/dnf install php-mbstring`. Puedes ejecutar temporalmente un [phpinfo();](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.phpinfo.php) para verificar si está cargado el módulo.